# Using filter method with array of NSManagedObject

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, filter, closures

I have a subclass of a NSManagedObject;

```
class Items: NSManagedObject {

@NSManaged var date: NSDate
@NSManaged var title: String
@NSManaged var folder: Folder
}
```

In my table view controller I fetch the `Items` and cast to an array, then I am trying create a new array by filtering the `Items` array. The filter should add all Items which have not got a `Folder` property to the array `unassignedItems`. However when using the filter method I get the error:

> Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((_) -> _)'

**Here is my array function:**

```
var unassignedItems = [Items]()

func loadData() {


    var items = [Items]()

    var error: NSError?

    let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: true)]
    items = moc?.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Items]

    unassignedNotes = items.filter{$0.folder == nil}

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

I have looked at other examples and other questions but still unable to find a solution for the filter closure. Does anybody know where I may be going wrong ?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're trying to use `filter` instead of using `NSPredicate` and having Core Data do the filtering for you?

Comment: I compiled the code without error. Are you sure you're getting the error from the *latest* build? Do a "clean" and a "build" from the "Product" menu. Also, you are assigning to `self.items` at the bottom of the function. I think you mean to assign to just `items`

Comment: @TomHarrington good question, I was migrating some of my code from a test swift playground to a iOS test app, I will try it out using predicate as it makes more sense when working with core data. I am still learning core data but will give it a go.